# Is it possible to use Flutter plugin in Native OS(iOS, Android)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, plugins, compatibility

Assume that I developed Flutter plugin about our company service.
Some clients want to use our plugin in their native app(iOS, Android).

This scenario can be possible?

Comment: If there is underlying Swift/Objective-C/Java/Kotlin code in your plugin then you can package that up separately for iOS and Android but those platforms can't use a Flutter plugin directly.  If your plugin is written in Dart then you can't provide it for use by native apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible to use Flutter plugin in Android studio.
The Android Studio IDE is a convenient way of integrating your Flutter module automatically. With Android Studio, you can co-edit both your Android code and your Flutter code in the same project. You can also continue to use your normal IntelliJ Flutter plugin functionalities such as Dart code completion, hot reload, and widget inspector.
Add-to-app flows with Android Studio are only supported on Android Studio 3.6 with version 42+ of the Flutter plugin for IntelliJ. The Android Studio integration also only supports integrating using a source code Gradle subproject, rather than using AARs. See below for more details on the distinction.
You can see in detail about that in https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup